# Date Code will only work in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time

The problem is that this program will only work in Chrome, no matter what date format I use or when I parsed the dates using , it would return NaN.

The program converts the two dates (constant and a certain holiday) into milliseconds from Jan 1st, 1970. The dates are compared and subtracted. Then they are divided and rounded into seconds until the date. The problem, I believe lies when the dates are set. I do **NOT** want to mess with timezones.

jQuery in the answer is fine. Regex's are fine, but I don't understand them.

If the answer could have a working proof, that would be cool. Thanks!

The html is (all that matters)

```
<p id="output">

</p>
```

The code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  console.log(year + "-12-25");
  var christmasdate = new Date(year + "-12-24 24:00:00");
  $("#output").css("font-size","20px");
  $("#output").html("If this lasts more than a second, something is wrong.");
  setInterval(function() {
    date = new Date();
    var curr_time = date.getTime();
    var xmas_time = christmasdate.getTime();
    var time_left = Math.round((xmas_time - curr_time) / 1000);
    var output;
    if (time_left < 0) {
      output = "Christmas was " + Math.abs(time_left) + " seconds ago."
    }
    else {
      output = "There is " + time_left + " seconds until christmas eve.";
    }
    if (time_left == 1) {
      output = "There is " + time_left + "second until christmas eve.";
    }
    $("#output").html(output);
    var bodyheight = $(document).height();
    var allheight = $("body").height();
    $("h2").css("margin-top",(bodyheight / 2) - (allheight / 2))
  }, 1000);
});
```

The link is http://jsbin.com/suyedol/5/edit.

Comment: `24:00:00` does not look like a valid time.

Comment: @cartant—it's as valid as 00:00:00 (see [*ECMA-262 §20.3.1.16Date Time String Format*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format): "*HH … two decimal digits from 00 to 24*"). But parsing strings with the Date constructor is to be strongly discouraged given the inconsistencies across implementations even where they attempt to conform to ECMA-262.

Comment: @RobG Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MDN:

> Because of the variances in parsing of date strings, it is recommended to always manually parse strings as results are inconsistent, especially across different ECMAScript implementations where strings like "2015-10-12 12:00:00" may be parsed to as NaN, UTC or local timezone.

But instead of

```
var christmasdate = new Date(year + "-12-24 24:00:00");
```

You could instead use:

```
var christmasdate = new Date(year,11,24,24,0,0);
```

Which Safari computed as

```
Mon Dec 25 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Comment: But it would be better to use `new Date(year, 11, 25)` to avoid confusion. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Your computation of christmas in the current year seems overly complex and error prone. You certainly should not be using the Date constructor to parse strings (or Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing).

Consider the following, which creates a date for 00:00:00 on Christmas morning in the current year.

```js
var christmas = new Date();
christmas.setHours(0,0,0,0);
christmas.setMonth(11,25);

console.log(christmas.toString());
```